# How to extend priority map to be reducable

Tags: clojure, extend, reduce

I noticed [priority map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/priority_map.clj) doesn't implement reduce (AbstractMethodError if you try) - how do I go about extending it so it can ?

Comment: `(reduce fn (seq (priority-map ...))`?

Comment: that's how to reduce with it, but I want to extend priority map so it can be used in existing reduce expressions without them needing to know it's a priority map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(ns reducing
   (:use clojure.data.priority-map)
   (:import (clojure.data.priority_map PersistentPriorityMap)))

(extend-type PersistentPriorityMap
   clojure.core.protocols/CollReduce
   (coll-reduce
      ([this f] (reduce f (seq this)))
      ([this f val] (reduce f (seq this) val))))

(def p (priority-map :a 2 :b 1 :c 3 :d 5 :e 4 :f 3))

(reduce conj [] p)
```

Comment: marking this as the accepted answer, as it was what I had in mind, but amalloy's patch is equally useful

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by some implicit assumptions clojure.core makes about implementations of collections, which as far as I know are not codified anywhere. Specifically, it assumes that all of the java collection interfaces are also implemented, but does not actually extend those interfaces. So, it's possible to forget to implement some of them, and then have things work fine until you get to some code that assumes they're implemented.

In this case, the interface that was missed (or one of them, at least) is Iterable: reduce can work on any Iterable without knowing anything more about it. I'll see about getting a patch applied to make priority-map implement Iterable.